# How can I see the list of files changed in last or a particular commit?

Tags: git

I always try to commit covering all my code with tests. But sometimes, I make too many changes and I commit even if not all code is covered. These times I need to check files changed last or a particular commit to see if are covered or not. Is will be useful to know a way to list (via console) all files changed in last commit. Last commit, or a particular commit. Now I do it with SourceTree but I dont love to pass from console to sourcetree and again to sourcetree to console.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just the filenames that were changed, try...

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only
```

It will show you all the files that changed in the last commit of the current branch you're on.

If you don't want to enter `less`, use...

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
```

Comment: How can I use "format:"? And, ... wow "git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD" is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

`git diff --name-only` or `git diff --name-status` are two standard ways to do this: you can give them any single commit, to compare the current work-tree to that commit, or any pair of commits to compare those two.

You can also add diff options to `git show`, so `git show --name-only` prints the log message and then the list of files; `git show --name-status` adds the status letters as well.  This works slightly differently for merge commits, as `git show` defaults to using a "combined diff" (see the [git diff documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html), about halfway down, about combined diffs; note that with `-m`, `git show` will produce multiple separate diffs instead).  (And as [alex noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22930995/1256452) you can alter or suppress the header information with `--pretty=format:<directives>`.)

I like one of the very old commands, `git whatchanged`, myself (it's a variant of `git log`; `git log --raw` does the same thing).  I have seen hints that `git whatchanged` might go away, but at least `git log --raw` should stick around.  The same output format is used in `git diff --raw`; again, see the [git diff documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).